# How can I select a specific rows in excel?

Tags: excel, analytics

I have a dataset which is an excel file.
It contains the information about the population change in the years 2010-16.
The data set rows consists of the information of the United states next the state and the county information for the state.
Now my question is how can I separate the state information and the county information in excel??
Here is the link to my data
https://www.ers.usda.gov/webdocs/DataFiles/CountyLevel_Data_Sets_Download_Data__18026/PopulationEstimates.xls?v=42489

Comment: What do you mean? Looking at the data, you want to just have a list of the States, separate from Counties? Why not just add a helper column, do say `=Iferror(Search("county",C4),C4,"")` which would check for "County" in the Column C cell, and return the State name, if there's no "county" text. *This assumes* that all cells *without* "county" are states.  What have you tried? What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want to divide the data into two excel files in such a way one file contains the data regarding the states and the other file contains the data regarding the counties but no information about the states.

Comment: I mean I want the excel file to be divided based on the row data

Answer (score 0):

You may try this macro which will create two sheets in the workbook one with state data and other with county data.

```
Sub SplitData()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsState As Worksheet, wsCounty As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsSource = Sheets("Population Estimates 2010-2015")
lr = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
Set wsState = Sheets("State")
Set wsCounty = Sheets("County")
wsState.Cells.Clear
wsCounty.Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
If wsState Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=wsSource).Name = "State"
    Set wsState = ActiveSheet
End If
If wsCounty Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=wsState).Name = "County"
    Set wsCounty = ActiveSheet
End If

With wsSource.Rows(3)
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="=*county*", Operator:=xlAnd
    wsSource.Range("A3:CW" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsCounty.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<>*county*", Operator:=xlAnd
    wsSource.Range("A3:CW" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsState.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter
End With
wsState.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
wsCounty.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested this code on your data and it worked perfectly. It created two sheets named State and County with their relevant data. It is hard to understand when you say it is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are needing to roll up data by counties and by states. Pivot tables should do this for you.

1. New sheet, insert, pivot table, select range (including headers but NOT including row 1 and 2)
2. Drop the values into the table how you need them, and remember to sum/average/count as needed
3. When you have the table with the right data, select it, copy, and "paste values" into another xls.

Do this twice, once for the county roll up and once for the state roll up.